# Adding two values and saving result for reuse

Tags: javascript

I have written a function where A and B are a random number between 1 and 6. I want the result of A and B to show up in Counter and save so when I click the add me button again it adds the result of a and b to the last result.

So if I click once and the Counter says 10.  I next time I click I get the result of 8.  I want the Counter to keep on adding the results together.

Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Javascript Counter</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
 
 .container {text-align: center; font-size: 20px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <p>The Counter = <span id="Count"> --- </span></p>

 <p>A = <span id="a1">?</span></p>
 <p>B = <span id="b1">?</span></p>

<input type="submit" value="Add Me" onclick="addTogether()" />

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  
 function addTogether(){
  var a1 = document.getElementById('a1');
  var b1 = document.getElementById('b1');
  var count = document.getElementById('Count');
  var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  
  var y = a + b ;

  a1.innerHTML = a;
  b1.innerHTML = b;
  count.innerHTML = y;

  

 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `count.innerHTML += y;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly. You just have to add the `count` to the `y` value.

```
y + (parseInt(count.innerHTML, 10)||0)
```

If you are instead wanting to save it through refreshes then you'll need to persist to localstorage or something.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Javascript Counter</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
 
 .container {text-align: center; font-size: 20px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <p>The Counter = <span id="Count"> --- </span></p>

 <p>A = <span id="a1">?</span></p>
 <p>B = <span id="b1">?</span></p>

<input type="submit" value="Add Me" onclick="addTogether()" />

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  
 function addTogether(){
  var a1 = document.getElementById('a1');
  var b1 = document.getElementById('b1');
  var count = document.getElementById('Count');
  var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  
  var y = a + b ;

  a1.innerHTML = a;
  b1.innerHTML = b;
  count.innerHTML = y + (parseInt(count.innerHTML, 10)||0);

  

 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or ... you can store the value in a global variable.  All the variables in your function are local to that function.  Another solution is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript Counter</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">

    .container {text-align: center; font-size: 20px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <p>The Counter = <span id="Count"> --- </span></p>

    <p>A = <span id="a1">?</span></p>
    <p>B = <span id="b1">?</span></p>

<input type="submit" value="Add Me" onclick="addTogether()" />

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 0;

    function addTogether(){
        var a1 = document.getElementById('a1');
        var b1 = document.getElementById('b1');
        var count = document.getElementById('Count');
        var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);

        counter = a + b + counter ;

        a1.innerHTML = a;
        b1.innerHTML = b;
        count.innerHTML = counter;



    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

(I'm sure it's also possible to use fancier techniques like a closure ...)